# Spring Autowiring can't see context beans unless component scanning defined on base package

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired

I currently have my spring application setting using @SpringBootApplication, everything is working however, I cannot inject beans defined in an xml using autowiring.

If I define the dependency injection through the xml configuration for the injection works like

```
<bean id="dao" class="com.elevations.dao.Dao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

However, if I denote my Application with @ComponentScanning( "elevations" ), (elevations is my base package) autowiring works, however then my controller end points stop working. Why is this the case?

My application com.elevations.Application is defined as

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run( Application.class, args );
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( "context.xml" );
    }
}
```

xml configuration defined as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.elevations.dao"/>

    <!--postgresql jdbc bean-->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" autowire="byType">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/elevationdb"/>
        <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="dao" class="com.elevations.dao.Dao"/>

</beans>
```

The test class I'm trying to autowire com.elevations.dao.Dao

```
@Component
public class Dao
{
    private DataSource m_dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource( DataSource dataSource )
    {
        m_dataSource = dataSource;
    }
}
```

Controller com.elevations.controllers.ApplicationController

```
@Controller
public class ApplicationController
{
    @RequestMapping( value = "/elevations", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public String pageGet()
    {
        return "elevationMaps";
    }

    @RequestMapping( value = "/elevationData", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    @ResponseBody
    public LatLng mapGet( @RequestParam( "bounds" ) String bounds, @RequestParam( "diameter") String diameter )
    {

        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement viewBounds = parser.parse( bounds );

        return new LatLng( 1, 0 );
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `@Autowire` so no auto wiring is done... If you don't specify the information nothing will happen.

Comment: Sorry I removed it, but if I have @Autowire I get an error saying it can't find a bean definition for DataSource

Comment: Ofcourse it cannot because your spring boot application doesn't know anything about your XML. Nor should it, use Spring Boot don't work against/around it. (that goes for any framework btw).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use xml add `@ImportResource` to your application class.

```
@ImportResource("context.xml")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run( Application.class, args );
    }
}
```

However I would strongly suggest ditching your xml, simply add an `application.properties` to `src/main/resources` and add the following properties.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/elevationdb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=
```

Then remove `@ImportResource` from your class and restart.